# Как семантически верно расположить боковое меню?

Tags: html, html5, семантика

Вопрос в следующем:

Как мне правильно расположить боковое меню?

Я говорю про HTML-разметку.

Пример такого меню на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, я столкнулся с мыслью, что в целом, можно просто накинуть `flex` на `body` или `dashboard-main` и спозиционировать меню слева.

Как то так:

```
<body>
    <div class="dashboard-main">
        <header class="header">
            123
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            123
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Но я не уверен в семантической правильности такого решения потому что насколько я знаю нельзя в `body` класть `div` и только потом, `header` и `main`.

Или может не париться и просто сделать `body -> header,main`?

Может кто-то подсказать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов это воспользоваться [тегом aside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside), что является достаточно распространенной практикой, например такую реализацию можно встретить на сайте [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com):

```html
<body>
    <div class="dashboard-main">
        <header class="header">
            123
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            123
        </main>
    </div>
    <aside>Ваше меню</aside>
</body>
```